# Get midnight epoch time in millis for a given epoch time in millis

Tags: java, java-8

What is the suggested way of getting midnight time in UTC for a given epoch time in millis? I tried the following which seems to work, wondering if there is a better/cleaner way of doing the same thing.

```
 public long toUtcMidnight(final Long date) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            .toLocalDate()
            .atStartOfDay()
            .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toEpochMilli();
    }
```

We could use Joda time for this, but I want to use only java 8 date library for this.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. You could also use the GregorianCalendar way, but I doubt it will be any better.

Comment: I don't like the fact that I have to provide the "UTC" twice, once as ZoneId and once as offset :(

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to *truncate* an `Instant` to the day. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

> Truncating the instant returns a copy of the original with fields
>   smaller than the specified unit set to zero.

Using `ChronoUnit.Days`, you would zero out hours, minutes, seconds, millis.

For example

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(date).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Definitely neat! Looks like truncate uses UTC internally.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's all UTC just do `millis/86400_000 * 86400_000`;

The long(int) division will truncate to days and * msecs/day will bring it back to msecs.

If needed you could truncate to weeks, hours or whatever you want.

Comment: Wondering if this could make the code less readable? The solution by Sotirios looks readable. Please let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: It depends, do you say "see ya tomorrow"  or "see ya in 86400 seconds"?  I think most programmers have memorized the common time units in msecs, but sometimes I see a static var `MSECS_PER_DAY`.  You'll also see `msecs % 86400_000` for the msec of the current day.

Answer (score 0):

What you have works but if you're looking for something a bit more readable, how about using Calendar?

```
 public long toUtcMidnight(long date) {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(date);
      cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      return cal.getTimeInMillis();   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to be working too hard.

I use the approach of calling `atStartOfDay` because I would use this for any time zone. The first moment of a day in some zones is *not* always `00:00:00.0`. And this approach works for UTC as well.

```
ZonedDateTime midnightUtc = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC );
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = midnightUtc.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "midnightUtc: " + midnightUtc );
System.out.println( "millisecondsSinceEpoch: " + millisecondsSinceEpoch );
```

When run.

> midnightUtc: 2015-09-26T00:00Z
>
> millisecondsSinceEpoch: 1443225600000

Comment: If needed for a given date instead of 'now', won't this roughly translate to the code originally proposed? Besides, I want to avoid repetitive usage of 'UTC' in the code (used twice here)

Comment: Yes my code is very close to yours. Great minds think alike. I would say mine is better in that breaking it up into two lines gives us a `ZonedDateTime` we can use in debugging, logging, and assertion-testing. As for the multiple use of the UTC constant, that is not repetitive. The java.time framework requires us to go through the "Local" class to call the start-of-day method. So we need to apply a time zone when leaving and re-joining the timeline. The Joda-Time library offered a `withTimeAtStartOfDay` method on its zoned date-time class (`DateTime`) but java.time does not (I'm not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really readable solution I use:

```
long fullMsecs = System.currentTimeMillis();
long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(msecs);
long truncatedMsecs = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
```

Or abbreviated:

```
long msecs = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```